# Import a URL with Ajax or Jsonp without iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, iframe

i have this simple index:

```
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="bottom: 0px;position: absolute;">
    <? include("inc/creditos.php")?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

creditos.php:

```
<script>
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(){                   
    $('#show_credits').click(function(){
        //$('iframe#cred').css("display","none");
        var pos=$(this).position();
        if (pos.left>200) pos.left=pos.left-250;                                  
            $('#cred').css("top",pos.top-240);                            
            $('#cred').css("left",pos.left);
            $('#cred').fadeIn("slow");
            //$("iframe#cred").contents().find("#creditos").css('display','none');
            $('#close').css("background-color","red");  
            $('#close').css("top",pos.top-223);                           
            $('#close').css("left",pos.left+293);
            $('#close').css("position","absolute");
            $('#close').fadeIn("slow");
            $('#close').css("z-index","1");
            $('#close').css("width","20px");
            $('#close').css("height","20px");           
        });

    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('#cred').fadeOut("slow");
        $('#close').fadeOut("slow");

});
    }); 
</script>
<iframe style="position:absolute;width:313px;height:234px;display:none;border:0;"id="cred" name="test_creditos" src="http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100909154419/mario/es/images/5/54/Flor_de_Fuego.jpg" scrolling="no"></iframe>
<a class="credits" href="javascript:void(0)" id="show_credits">Cr&eacute;ditos</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" id="close" style="display:none;"></a>
```

Can i do the same with Ajax or Jsonp without iframe (Call and import the image when i click "Creditos")?

I need delete the iframe and get the same result :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `jQuery.get()` to retrieve a file at a URL and then do whatever you want with the contents: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Answer (score 0):

You're displaying an image. There is no need to muck about with Ajax.

Create an image element.

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
```

Set the mandatory attributes:

```
image.src = "http://img1.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20100909154419/mario/es/images/5/54/Flor_de_Fuego.jpg";
image.alt = "Something suitable here";
```

Add it to the document:

```
document.body.appendChild(image);
```